# "Error Extra }, or forgotten $" in a diagram using forest environment

Tags: beamer, math-mode, errors, forest

I am trying to make a tree diagram in beamer using math mode in nodes but I receive the message  error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<template> \unskip \hfil }
                      \endtemplate 
l.130 \end{frame}
```

my code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[block=fill,numbering=fraction,progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Stability}

\begin{forest}
forked edges, 
for tree={draw,align=center,edge={-latex}}
[$|f'(x^{\ast})|=1$
[$f'(x^{\ast})=1$
[$f''(x^{\ast})\neq 0$ [$x^{\ast}$ is unstable] ]
[$f''(x^{\ast})=0$ 
[$f'''(x^{\ast})<0$ [$x^{\ast}$ is asymptotically stable] ]
[$f'''(x^{\ast})>0$ [$x^{\ast}$ is unstable ] ] ] ]
[$f'(x^{\ast})=-1$
[$Sf(x^{\ast})<0$ [$x^{\ast}$ is asymptotically stable] ]
[$Sf(x^{\ast})>0$ [$x^{\ast}$ is unstable] ] ] ]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I really cannot imagine what is missing or going wrong!!! Please help!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community.

Answer (score 2):

The `=` sign has special usage in forest to separate keys from their values. To tell forest that your `=` is not part of any key value pairs, wrap `{...}` around your text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[block=fill,numbering=fraction,progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Stability}

\scriptsize

\begin{forest}
forked edges, 
for tree={draw,align=center,edge={-latex}}
[{$|f'(x^{\ast})|= 1$}
[{$f'(x^{\ast})= 1$}
[$f''(x^{\ast})\neq 0$ [$x^{\ast}$ is unstable] ]
[{$f''(x^{\ast})= 0$} 
[$f'''(x^{\ast})<0$ [$x^{\ast}$ is asym. stable] ]
[$f'''(x^{\ast})>0$ [$x^{\ast}$ is unstable ] ] ] ]
[{$f'(x^{\ast})= -1$}
[$Sf(x^{\ast})<0$ [$x^{\ast}$ is asym. stable] ]
[$Sf(x^{\ast})>0$ [$x^{\ast}$ is unstable] ] ] ]
\end{forest}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: forest diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Using return command, I noticed that the problem is the use of the symbol of equality "=".
I really can't understand why, but I replaced it with \equiv and it worked!